# Should i care about filtering $nin ids from $in ids before querying mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, benchmarking

So i have a some node.js code, which has a lit of $in and $nin ids for mongodb.

The list of "$nin" is actually way bigger than the "$in" list.

On "my implementation" i did it the "easy way", by passing both ids lists to mongodb:

`query = { _id: { $in: in_list, $nin: not_in_list } }`

My colleague then came, and removed all the "$nin" ids from the "$in" list, and just queried for $in

`in_list = _.difference in_list, not_in_list
query = { _id: { $in: in_list } }`

My assumption would be, mongodb is smart enough to deal with this faster more efficiently than node.js but i don't actually know if this difference is actually measurable and/or significant.

Any input?

Comment: Why not test out the two approaches and compare the performance?

Comment: I'm in hope someone with good experience on benchmarking can enlighten us with a good method for benchmark this.

At the moment i would just be able to run like 1000x each of them and compare, but i suspect this would not be the "proper way" !?

Comment: What this is basically going to come down to is which is better at crunching the numbers for you. Sending all the results over the wire for the query optimizer to pull the difference in lists or working out that difference in the client. It's likely subjective to the size of the lists. How about you benchmark both an post your findings as your answer. Others might find it useful. BTW your comment responses are from two of the people with arguably the most experience around here.

Comment: I wasn't considering the network latency/cost ( so obvious!! )

The app will be running for years, and this lists will get quite big for active users.

I believe in crunching them on the "code" ( as opposite to mongo ) will be the right thing, as we have auto-scaling for this cluster and mongodb has just a small fixed number of instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $in will be faster. Either query needs to scan each document in the results set, so if you have a smaller number of items needed to fulfill the $in query than the $nin query, use that.

Comment: That's not how it works. The optimizer will negate the lists in a similar way to the proposed client operation. The only question her e comes down to is it more expensive to sent all of that over the wire to the server to do that or to allow the likely lesser powered client to process the code. The general suspicion is that the network cost is greater than the slower processing of the client. But this does not "intersect" two result sets like you suggest.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Didn't know the optimizer did that, but that make sense. Thanks for the tip.